# Skipping a command when app is freezing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can I handle the problem when in my app somebody set a wrong IP address to socket communication?
The app is freezing at line, where the socket is waiting for answer from the server. (i'm using SmallSockets)
Is it posible to make a timer for this command, and after the timer count down skip this command?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be handling synchronous network communications on the main thread. You should be doing networking stuff asynchronously. Here's [an example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008979) that should get you going.

Using an asynchronous approach, you should be able to cancel a network operation after a timeout easily.